# Authentification to Azure Ad in Angular using Msal

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal

I would authentificate to Azure AD .

I have Configured my app in `module.app`

```
MsalModule.forRoot({
  clientID: "ClientId",
  authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/",
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
  validateAuthority : true,
  cacheLocation : "localStorage",
  postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
  navigateToLoginRequestUrl : true,
  popUp: true,
  consentScopes: ["user.read", "api://??what_Id_Sould_I_Put???/access_as_user"],
  unprotectedResources: ["https://angularjs.org/"],
  correlationId: '1234',
  piiLoggingEnabled: true,
}),
```

I my component I use `loginPopup` method for connexion:

```
this.authService.loginPopup(["user.read" ,"api://ClientId/access_as_user"]);
```

I get this error

> AADSTS50001: The application named api://ClientId was not found in the tenant named de5e3c28-141c-4d3e-90ea-aa3326abe67d (Strange ID ). This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

In the [sample demo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/samples/MSALAngularDemoApp/src/app/app.module.ts) the **ID** used in **ConsentScope** variable is different than the **Client ID**, I don't know what is that ID and how to get it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line

```
consentScopes: ["user.read", "api://??what_Id_Sould_I_Put???/access_as_user"],
```

from the config.
And change the line

```
this.authService.loginPopup(["user.read" ,"api://ClientId/access_as_user"]);
```

to

```
this.authService.loginPopup();
```